# Laravel Eloquent Model: Automatically create values

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my application, I have a model, e.g., a *Post* model. Whenever there is a new entry which does not fill all columns, I'd like to calculate the values for the remaining columns. For example the title for the new post is `$post->title = 'Foo Bar'`, then I'd like the slug to be `$post->slug = 'foo-bar'` **automatically**.

However, where can I do that? Is there maybe an option to do so in the model itself? I do not really want to do so in the controller.

Comment: You could use [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) or use any [event](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events) (depends when you want this to exists)

Comment: Take a look at the [Spatie Sluggable](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable) package which deals with creating and updating the slug as well as checking for duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `Post` Model:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
```

And then create a static boot function like below in the Post Model:

```
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function ($post) {
        $post->slug = Str::slug($post->title);
        // add other column as well
    });

    static::updating(function ($post) {
         $post->slug = Str::slug($post->title);
         // add other column as well
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thin using boot method is a good solution, an alternative will be using model [observer](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers). On **creating** event, you can create the slug and save it.

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\Models\Post;

class PostObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the Post "creating" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Post  $Post
     * @return void
     */
    public function creating(Post $post)
    {
        $post->slug = Str::slug($post->title);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a Mutator in model for remaining columns.

Docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator

```
public function setTitleAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['title'] = $value;
    $this->attributes['slug'] = str_slug($value); 
}
```

You can define mutators like this for others columns too